# What is Katakuri's power?

Tags: one-piece

> Katakuri is one of the sweet generals in big mom army and the strongest one of them.

we saw him

> growing extra limb or moving them like an octopus. At some point he even performed the Elephant Gun move that is a signature move of Luffy with rubber body. He can also predict the future to some degree.

So what is his powers exactly? is he a devil fruit user or this is just some other race in One Piece world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His power comes from a devil fruit, a "special" type of the paramecia called Mochi Mochi no Mi. Although this fruit is a paramecia type, so far its characteristics have been more inline with the Logia, as the user can become "intangible" to avoid attacks. An example is when Ichiji tried to hit Katakauri
[image]

Also worth of nothing is that in the first translations, the fruit type was labeled as Logia but was later changed to a special type of paramecia(i would say because mochi is not a natural element).

Regarding to his ability to predict the future, its just a further developed observation haki. Usually this type of haki was shown to enable the user to perceive what kind of attack the enemy will use, so its a natural extension to be able to predict the movement of your surrounding in the future.

Info about mochi mochi no mi:
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mochi_Mochi_no_Mi

Wiki about mochi, if you want to eat some cake 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mochi

Comment: thanks but if I recall correctly, when luffy was about to burst out of the wedding cake he said he had seen Every possible future and there was no avoiding it. how can he do that with just observation haki?

Comment: It meant he had no way of changing what was gonna to happen even if he saw it. He had no way of stop it, even if he foresaw it coming. Even if you know something will happen, like a plane will crash in 10 minutes you cant do anything to stop the crash. Something similar happened there, he knew what is going to happen but he cannot stop it.

Comment: Nice answer, even I am amazed about Observation Haki

Comment: in the newest chapter, he used elephant gun just like luffy. BUT its more bigger and more powerful. I would say, it's like a rubber, because "mochi" texture is similar wih rubber.

Comment: what do you mean by "special"?